# How do I programmatically update the order status?

Tags: 8, commerce, payment-gateways

After Payment is accepted, I need to update the order status to "Completed" from the page controller.

How do I do this, on Drupal 8?

I find no documentation about this; there is an example for Drupal 7.

```
// Updating Order status.
$orderObj = commerce_order_load($orderID);
commerce_order_status_update($orderObj, 'canceled', TRUE, 'Order Voided');
$orderObj->log = 'Order cancelled programatically';
commerce_order_save($orderObj);
```

Answer (score 9):

You want to use the State Machine methods of the Commerce Order class.

It would be something like this, but it will depend on what you called your order states.

```
$order_state = $orderObj->getState();
$order_state_transitions = $order_state->getTransitions();
$order_state->applyTransition($order_state_transitions['complete']);

$orderObj->save();
```

If you aren't sure, you can always check the `$order_state_transitions` array to see what options you have.

Comment: I think the state that needs to be set (default setup) is "placed"; also, i think you are missing a line where you need to assign the $order_state back to the Order before saving it.

Comment: No, you don't. Setting the state yourself would go against the pattern. You are welcome to post your own answer.

Comment: Yes, my idea was wrong. I posted a similar question (and answered it) here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/292291/how-do-i-programmatically-place-an-order

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking to "place" the order. You need to subscribe to the Event handler for this event: commerce_order.order.paid

and with this handler code:

```
  public function paymentCompletedHandler($event) {
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    $order->getState()->applyTransitionById('place');
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code did the job for me. You need to know the ID of the transition. In my case, it's '**cancel**'

```
$order = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order::load($order_id);
$order_state = $order->getState();
$order_state->applyTransitionById('cancel');
$order->save();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use set method.

```
$order->set('state', 'completed');
$order->save();
```

Comment: this will bypass state transitions and break commerce_stock, potentially skip notifications, and other modules that hook into state transitions